# Applications that use connection and connectionless oriented services

Tags: networking, routes, connection, forwarding

What kind of program use connection less and connection oriented communication?
I know this is a simple questions but I have no idea where to find anything.

I thought that applications like Skype or a VPN could use connection oriented services because they would require a direct constant path to the destination so that there is a minimal amount of packet loss and all packets come in order.

But what applications could use a connection less oriented service?
I thought maybe a connection of a video game server or a database server.

I would appreciate some feedback on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding here is the basic examples of both type of services

```
Connetion Oriented: 
Reliable message stream => Sequence of pages 
Reliable byte stream    => Remote Login
Unreliable Connection   => Digitized voice

Connection Less:
Unreliable Datagram     => Electronic junk mail
Acknowledged Datagram   => Registered mail
Request - reply         => Database query
```

For better understanding http://courses.iddl.vt.edu/CS1604/15-Lesson_14/04-Connection-Oriented_vs_Connectionless.php

Comment: Registered mail is not a computer application (I assume the question was concerned about computers). Furthermore, email being online equivalent of registered mail would use a connection-oriented protocol, such as TCP.